# Spring - Treat incoming date as UTC

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I have application written in spring that allows user to filter data by date.

Filters model:

```
data class FilterCommand(
        @field:DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") val dateFrom: Date?,
        @field:DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") val dateTo: Date?,
        val author: String?,
        val state: String?
)
```

Everything works fine, except when user chooses `07/06/2019` in UI, I get exactly same value in Spring in current timezone.
Is it possible to tell spring to treat this incoming data as UTC?
Or to convert it somehow on model level?

Date I receive: `Fri Jun 07 00:00:00 CEST 2019`
Date I would like to get: `Fri Jun 07 00:00:00 UTC 2019`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the timezone directly in the JVM, so if you set it to UTC, all dates will be on UTC.

Comment: I know, but I would like to avoid changing timezone globally.